# ceiling and floor functions used as min and max: ever seen?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

I remember seeing somewhere people using symbols for ceiling and floor operators together with super/subscripts as substitutes for min and max. Example: `\lceil x \rceil ^k` to mean `\min(x,k)`.

Has anyone ever seen this too? I know it's not a pure Latex question but I think people in this forum have seen a lot of notations and might help. Thanks!

Comment: I have never seen this, but I'd consider it bad notation, because it can be confused with the exponential and, more importantly, is not symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

You are certainly free to set up your own math notation -- and TeX and LaTeX make it straightforward to do so.

E.g., you could provide a sentence such as

```
Let $\lceil x \rceil ^k \equiv \min(x,k)$.
```

early on in your paper to introduce the notation to your readers. If you have a lot of these terms, you may want to define a macro named, say, `\mymin`, via

```
\newcommand\mymin[2]{\lceil #1 \rceil ^#2}
```

in the preamble and write `$\mymin{x}{k}$` in the body of the document.